# How compare an array of objects using chai?

Tags: javascript, chai

I am trying to create a test to verify that when I send a request to add a provider, that value is stored in the database.
The test is sending the request, the provider is created, but when I am trying to add the assertions to check the values in the database, I can't.

```
let providerBd = await functions.getProvider(addProviderRequest.senderID);
console.log(providerBd);
expect(providerBd.razonsocial).to.equal(testCase.provider.senderAdminName);
```

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NNoTN.png)

First I am logging the object with the value obtained in the DB. But the test fails because the value that it gets is undefined and I am expected 'Proveedor Mocha' in razonsocial.

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CV8xI.png)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `to.equal`, -> `.should.eventually.equal`   more info -> https://www.chaijs.com/plugins/chai-as-promised/

Answer (score 0):

My error is in this line:
expect(providerBd.razonsocial).to.equal(testCase.provider.senderAdminName);

It should be:
expect(providerBd[0].razonsocial).to.equal(testCase.provider.senderAdminName);

Now works :)

Answer (score 0):

```js
let providerBd = await functions.getProvider(addProviderRequest.senderID);
expect(new Set(providerBd.razonsocial)).to.equal(new Set(testCase.provider.senderAdminName));
```

Comment: Care for some explanation of your `new Set` addition?